# Find a change-of-coordinates matrix $P$ and use it to show that $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 
> 1 & 5 \\
> -1 & 3 
> \end{bmatrix}$ act on $\mathbb{C}^2$.  An eigenvector of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 
> 1-2i \\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $2+2i$.  Find a change-of-coordinates matrix $P$ and use it to show that $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 
> a & -b \\
> b & a 
> \end{bmatrix}$.

I know that Eigenvectors for $\begin{bmatrix} 
a & -b \\
b & a 
\end{bmatrix}$. are  $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$. I believe I need to make a augmented matrix and row reduce yet still unsure how to approach it.

Comment: A real polynomial has conjugate roots.

Comment: They will be similar if they have common eigenvalues. From this you obtain $a,b.$ Then one can go through the diagonalization on each of matrices. There can exist a more elegant method...this one will works as well.

Comment: Play around with the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing, we have

$A u = \mu u; \tag 1$

since $A$ is real the eigenvalues are either real or occur in complex conjugate pairs; thus we may write

$\mu = \mu_R + i\mu_I, \tag 2$

$A$ being a real matrix, if $\mu \in \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R$, the vector $u \in \Bbb C^2$ may be written in terms of real and imaginary parts

$u = u_R + iu_I, \; u_R, u_I \in \Bbb R^2; \tag 3$

with $u_I \ne 0$; then we have

$Au_R + iAu_I = A(u_R + iu_I)$
$= (\mu_R + i\mu_I)(u_R + iu_I) = \mu_R u_R - \mu_I u_I + i(\mu_I u_R + \mu_R u_I), \tag 4$

which leads to

$Au_R = \mu_R u_R - \mu_I u_I, \tag 5$

$Au_I = \mu_I u_R + \mu_R u_I; \tag 6$

let

$U = [u_R \; u_I]; \tag 7$

that is, the columns of $U$ are the respective real and imaginary parts $u_R$ and $u_I$ of $u$; then we have

$AU = [Au_R \; Au_I] = [\mu_R u_R - \mu_I u_I \; \mu_I u_R + \mu_R u_I] = \mu_R[u_R \; u_I] + \mu_I[-u_I \; u_R]; \tag 8$

furthermore, in the event that

$\mu_I \ne 0, \tag 9$

the vectors $u_R$ and $u_I$ are linearly independent, for if $a, b \in \Bbb R$ are such that

$au_R + bu_I = 0, \tag{10}$

then

$aAu_R + bAu_I = 0; \tag{11}$

which *via* (5) and (6) becomes

$a(\mu_R u_R - \mu_I u_I) + b(\mu_I u_R + \mu_R u_I) = 0, \tag{12}$

or

$(a\mu_R + b\mu_I)u_R + (b\mu_R - a \mu_I)u_I = 0; \tag{13}$

if we multiply (10) by $\mu_R$ and subtract the result from this equation we obtain

$b\mu_I u_R - a\mu_I u_I = 0; \tag{14}$

in the event that (9) binds this becomes

$bu_R - au_I = 0; \tag{15}$

multiplying (10) by $b$ and (15) by $a$ and subtracting the resulting two equations yields

$(a^2 + b^2)u_I = 0; \tag{16}$

since $u_I \ne 0$ we find

$a^2 + b^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow a = b = 0, \tag{17}$

which shows that $u_R$ and $u_I$ are linearly independent; therefore the matrix $U$ in (7) is nonsingular and we have

$I = U^{-1}U = U^{-1}[u_R \; u_I] = [U^{-1}u_R \; U^{-1}u_I] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{18}$

$U^{-1}AU = [Au_R \; Au_I] = \mu_R[U^{-1}u_R \; U^{-1}u_I] + \mu_I[-U^{-1}u_I \; U^{-1}u_R]$
$= \mu_R\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \mu_I \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_R & \mu_I \\ -\mu_I & \mu_R \end{bmatrix}, \tag{19}$

which shows that $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form

$\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_R & \mu_I \\ -\mu_I & \mu_R \end{bmatrix}, \tag{20}$

*via* the "change-of-coordinates" matrix $P = U$.

In the specific situation at hand, we are given that

$\mu = 2 + 2i; u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - 2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + i \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}; \tag{21}$

thus,

$u_R = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},  \tag{22}$

$u_I = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{23}$

$P = U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{24}$

$\mu_R = \mu_I = 2, \tag{25}$

and the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} \mu_R & \mu_I \\ -\mu_I & \mu_R \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{26}$

$OE\Delta$.